# using BeautifulSoup in scraping and put it inside for loop for no of pages but it is not working

Tags: beautifulsoup

I a trying to perform a web scraping using BeautifulSoup , by using below codes I get syntax error

```
for page in range (1): 
    print('---' , page , '---')
    r=requests.get(url + str(page))
    print(url+str(page)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.praser')
   
    break
```

my result is

```
File "<ipython-input-15-fc02eebf8442>", line 7
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.praser')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an closing `)` missing - try this:

```
for page in range (1): 
    print('---' , page , '---')
    r=requests.get(url + str(page))
    print(url+str(page))
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.praser')
   
    break
```